# Is $dQ = nC_pdT$ always true?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

We derived $dU = nC_vdT$ taking $dV = 0$. But we found that this is [true](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/565660/167872) not only for $dV=0$, but for all cases.

Similarly, we derived $dQ = nC_pdT$ taking $dp = 0$. So, can we say that this is true for all cases as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Similarly, we derived $dQ = nC_pdT$ taking $dp = 0$. So, can we say
> that this is true for all cases as well?

No.

First of all, a differential change in internal energy $dU$ between two equilibrium states does not depend on the path (process) connecting the two points. That's because internal energy is a property of the system, like temperature, pressure, volume, etc.. So if $dU=nC_{v}dT$ for an ideal gas for a constant volume process, its the same for any process connecting the two states. As @Chet Miller points out, it is also important to note that this equation for $dU$ only applies to ideal gas behavior. For real gases $dU$ is also a function of volume according to (for one mole of gas):

$$dU=C_vdT+\left[P-T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V\right]dV$$For an ideal gas, the term in brackets is zero.

Heat $Q$, like work $W$, is not a property of the system. Heat and work transfer between the system and surroundings depends on the process. So for an ideal gas the heat transfer that occurs in a process connecting two equilibrium states does depend on the process that connects the two paths. So $dQ=nC_{p}dT$ only applies to a constant pressure gas process and $dQ=nC_{v}dT$ only applies to a constant volume gas process.

Another point. You can have heat transfer without a temperature change. It occurs during a phase change such as solid to liquid or liquid to gas. During a phase change where $dP=0$ and $dT=0$, but $Q≠0$. During such a phase change the equation to use is $Q=mh$ where $h$ is the latent heat of fusion or vaporization.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is important to also mention that, for gases beyond the ideal gas region, the internal energy actually is also a function of specific volume.

Comment: @ChetMiller Right. I keep thinking in terms of ideal gas behavior.

Comment: @ChetMiller Hope you don't mind but I plagiarized you real gas equation.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. $Q$ is not a state function, but a path function. It depends on the path you take, in addition to the initial and the final state of the system. Thus, we cannot adequately express $\mathrm d Q$ as a function of only the temperature difference $\mathrm d T$, we need to also account in the nature of the path taken by the system.